# Passing contextual information to an RNN

Tags: neural-network, rnn

I've been experimenting with RNNs for predictive typing at both the letter and word level in TensorFlow and Keras, with great success so far.

In some cases we know about the context in which a user is typing a message. For example the time of day, the frequency at which messages are being exchanged, or the gender of the recipient. Giving the RNN this information could produce better predictions.

All the example RNNs I've been working from have only passed the relevant series - times series, text, musical notes, etc. Is it reasonable to simply pass time, gender and frequency data into the RNN mixed with the text representations?

The orignal training data would look like this:

```
I may admit at the outset th
 may admit at the outset tha
may admit at the outset that
ay admit at the outset that 
y admit at the outset that I
```

Could I just include contextual information with text?

```
M 12:09PM 27s I may admit at the outset th
M 12:09PM 27s  may admit at the outset tha
M 12:09PM 28s may admit at the outset that
M 12:10PM 29s ay admit at the outset that 
M 12:10PM 30s y admit at the outset that I
```

Comment: Yes, you can, and there are several ways: as an initial value for the state, as an input feature, or as an output feature that is combined with the state of the RNN before prediction.